# TypeError : Inputs to a layer should be tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am new to deep learning currently trying to learn neural network.However,I encountered this problem while training the neural network.

> This is the input .I thought by using the tensor Dataset I am ready to pass the values into the model I build.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train.values, trainLabel.values))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test.values, testLabel.values))
cv_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val.values, valLabel.values))

for features, targets in train_dataset.take(5):
  print ('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(features, targets))
```

This is the output shown from the print method above:

```
Features: [ 0 40  0  0  0  1 31 33 17], Target: 29
Features: [ 0 32  0  1  0  1 50 55 44], Target: 7
Features: [ 0 32  1  0  1  1 12 43 31], Target: 34
Features: [ 0 29  1  1  1  0 56 52 37], Target: 14
Features: [ 0 25  0  0  1  1 29 30 15], Target: 17
```

This is my model using Keras API:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(9,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])
```

I am trying to preview the output before training the neural network.

```
predictions = model(train_dataset)
predictions[:5]
```

However, I got this error :

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 9), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
```

> I googled myself to search for the error and found this line of code but still not working, at least for me

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error, you're providing `BatchDataset` to the model. Instead, you must change the input data into an array before feeding that into the model and do the model definition and compile the model.

```
train = np.array(train)
train

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train, trainLabel)

for features, targets in train_dataset.take(5):
  print ('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(features, targets))

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(32) 
#type(train_dataset) --->tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset
```

The below code will give you only a preview of an already existing dataset without any changes:

```
predictions = model(train)
predictions[:5]
```

Hence, you need to train the model with input data and then check for predictions:

```
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)

predictions = model(train)
predictions[:5]
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 7.51 ],
       [10.033],
       [11.349],
       [ 9.586],
       [ 9.86 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Note: I have used the [abalone dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) to replicate this code.