# Tensorflow layer expects 1 tensor input, but getting two tensor input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to deep learning currently trying to learn neural network.However,I encountered this problem while training the neural network.

This is the input .I thought by using the tensor Dataset I am ready to pass the values into the model I build.My train.values is the feature while trainLabel is the label(output)

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train.values, trainLabel.values))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test.values, testLabel.values))
cv_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val.values, valLabel.values))

for features, targets in train_dataset.take(5):
  print ('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(features, targets))


Features: [ 0 40  0  0  0  1 31 33 17], Target: 29
Features: [ 0 32  0  1  0  1 50 55 44], Target: 7
Features: [ 0 32  1  0  1  1 12 43 31], Target: 34
Features: [ 0 29  1  1  1  0 56 52 37], Target: 14
Features: [ 0 25  0  0  1  1 29 30 15], Target: 17
```

This is my model using Keras API:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(32,9)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])
```

I am trying to preview the output before training the neural network.

```
train_iterator = train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
one_batch = train_iterator.next()
predictions = model(train_dataset)
predictions[:5]
```

However, I got this error :

```
ValueError: Layer "sequential_2" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(9,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([ 0, 32,  0,  1,  1,  1, 15, 15,  5])>, 13]
```

Solution:

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72568479/typeerror-inputs-to-a-layer-should-be-tensor) issue in Stackoverflow and please refer to the answer mentioned in the answer section.

Please change the `input_shape` in the model definition here likewise mentioned in your other issue to avoid this value error.

```
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(9,)),
```